# OpenAPI 3 / Spring Boot @RequestPart is not optional

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, openapi-generator

I have a little problem with creating upload path in my API. 
In example :

```
/test/upload:
    post:
      operationId: post form attachemnts
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data: 
            schema:            
              type: object
              required:
                - testId
              properties:
                testId:
                  type: string
                  example: 1
                document:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
```

I want to send testId (Required - this is ok), but my document (jpg,pdf) must be optional.

Piece of code created by openapi-generator-maven-plugin:4.2.3:

```
@RequestParam(value="testId", required=true)  String testId,@ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart("document") MultipartFile document
```

When i send post in postman with filled testId only, I recive :
`"Required request part 'document' is not present"`

I think problem is in part `@RequestPart("document") MultipartFile document` and correct code generated should look like this `@RequestPart(value="document", required=false) MultipartFile document`. But how achive this?

Document created in Swagger Editor, OpenAPI 3.0.2, SB 2.2.1.RELEASE
Declared dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: this is reported here https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/6677

Comment: and actually fixed in `5.x.x` https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5573

Answer (score 0):

redefine in your `CONTROLLER` this parameter

```
@RequestPart("document") on @RequestPart(value = "document", required = false)
```